# How to disable momentarily onClick event of ImageView and Button in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have 2 elements:

```
Button answer;
Imageview play;
```

When 'answer' is clicked - the app records the user.
When 'play' is clicked - the app plays a clue to the user.
So when one of the above is clicked, the other should be disabled and not allow an onclick event.
Problem is - I've tried both setClickable() and setEnabled() but they don't do what I expected them to do.
Also, I've tried using a boolean flag, but it also didn't do the trick.
What am I doing wrong?
Here is the attempt with the boolean flag:

```
answer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mIsAudioResourcesFree)
        {
            mIsAudioResourcesFree = false;
//RECORDS AND STOPS RECORDING
            mIsAudioResourcesFree = true;
        }
    }
});

play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mIsAudioResourcesFree)
                {
                    mIsAudioResourcesFree = false;
                    //PLAYS SOME SHORT AUDIO
                    mIsAudioResourcesFree = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: `mIsAudioResourcesFree` will be change to true immediately .. You said you are playing a file .. So you should be using some Completion Listener to reset the `mIsAudioResourcesFree` cause file can be of any length ..

Comment: i agree with @ADM, using `answer.setEnabled(false);` definitely will disable the button, so it's probably something else giving you problems